# How can one build this kind of graphics? What kind of plot is it?

Tags: plotting, graphics, piecewise

[image: movement equation]
i want to know how can i build this kind of plot?
its a graphic of Moment -150 to 150(H.m)in fuction of time from 0 to 6 seconds.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I hope you will become a regular contributor. To get started, 1) take the [introductory tour](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour) now, 2) when you see good questions and answers, vote them up by clicking the [gray triangles](http://i.stack.imgur.com/eNrdG.png), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge,

Comment: 3) remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, by clicking the [checkmark sign](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work), and 4) give help too, by answering questions in your areas of expertise.

Comment: Assuming that you have data then use [`ListLinePlot`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ListLinePlot.html)

Answer (score 4):

One possible implementation could be:

```
Labeled[
 Plot[
  Piecewise[
   {{100, x < 1}
    , {-100 x + 200, 1 <= x < 3}
    , {-100, 3 <= x < 4}
    , {200 x - 900, 4 <= x < 5}
    , {100, 5 <= x < 6}
    , {True, 100}
    }
   ]
  , {x, -1, 7}
  , PlotRange -> {-160, 160}
  , PlotStyle -> Thick
  , GridLines -> None
  , AspectRatio -> 5/10
  , Ticks -> {Range[1, 6], Automatic}
  , AxesLabel -> {"xlabel", "ylabel"}
  , Epilog -> {Red, Dashed,
    , Line[{{1, 100}, {1, 0}}]
    , Line[{{5, 100}, {5, 0}}]
    }
  ]
 , Style["PlotLabel", Red, 12]
 , Bottom
 ]
```

[image]

Comment: You can use `, AxesStyle -> Arrowheads[{0.0, 0.03}]` to draw arrowheads on axes.